# ¿Como puedo sustituir la imagen?

Tags: angular

**.ts**

```
  public change() {
this.logo.nativeElement.src=data.image ;
  }
```

No me detecta el "logo" ni el date.imge

**html**

```
  <img class="img-position" #logo src={{img}}>
<img [src]="data.image" [width]="cropperSettings.croppedWidth" [height]="cropperSettings.croppedHeight">
<button md-raised-button color="accent" (click)="change()">
```

Answer (score 2):

Como dijo "Jack, el destripador":

> Vayamos por partes

- `Logo`: Esta variable no te la detecta en el `change()` porque no se la estás pasando:

**Template**

```
       <img class="img-position" #logo src="{{img}}">
       <input type="button" md-raised-button color="accent" (click)="change(logo)" value="Cambiar"/>
```

**Component**

```
    change(logo){
       logo.src=data.image;
    }
```

> Nota: No hay que acceder a `nativeElement` (que en este caso sería
>   `undefined`).

- `Data`: ¿Puedes indicarnos cómo estás definiendo el objeto `data`?

Me he creado una interfaz de prueba y me funciona sin problemas:

**Component**

```
      interface Data{
         image: string;
      }

      data: Data;

      ngOnInit(){ 
        this.data= {image: "ruta a mi imagen"};
```

**Template**

```
       <img [src]="data.image">
```

En cuanto veamos cómo construyes el objeto edito la respuesta con la posible solución.